# Discord - Automatically extract a message immediately after it appears in a channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am yet to code this but actually struggling to understand how to do this

There is a private server with paid membership. I am a member. There are many channels on that server. I am particularly interested in a specific channel. Once someone posts a message in that channel, I want to immediately extract that message from a different program automatically and then process it in downstream systems. How to do that?

Comment: Do you have administrator permissions on the server? Or will an admin add the bot to the server? You can't gather anything without having a discord bot on the server with permissions to see the channel.

Comment: You could set up a web scraper such as Puppeteer or Cheerio then login to Discord through a web browser. Access your channel and listen for new message elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late to this question, but I'm going to tell you the secrets the Discord elites don't want you to know: *This is completely doable, and many people do it*. It's called a "self-bot".

**Disclaimer**: As the other answer stated, this is against ToS. You probably won't be caught, but I'd keep this on the down-low. Definitely **don't** go around telling this to everyone you meet.

Ok, now here's the actual coding part:

Discord.js, the most common library for discord bots in JavaScript, no longer supports self-bots, so you'll need to use an older version of discord.js. The official old versions have some unresolved bugs when used with modern discord, so I like to go with [discord.js.v11.patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js.v11.patch). Using this patched package will fix any weird bugs you get. **Note**: this is still discord.js v11, so if you need documentation, be sure to look at the v11 docs.

Ok, so after you run `npm install discord.js.v11.patch` (or `npm install -g discord.js.v11.patch` if you want to install it globally), you'll need to start writing code. Everything is basically the same as any old discord.js bot, but this is v11 so some stuff might be different. Here's some code to get you started. It should do everything you want it to do:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js.v11.patch');
const client = new discord.Client();

const USER_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // change this to your token
const CHANNEL_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // change this to the chanel you want to listen to.

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is running');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.id != CHANNEL_ID) return;
    const message_text = msg.content;

    console.log(message_text); // just an example
    // send message_text somewhere to process it.
});

client.login(USER_TOKEN);
```

Now, all you need to do is change `USER_TOKEN` to your discord token and `CHANNEL_ID` to the ID of the channel you want to listen to.

To get your token, I recommend using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gamerboytr/90ab13b0c61c6888dae329199ea6aff3). It is safe and minimal. If you are worried about accessing your token, don't be. As long as you don't give it to anyone else you're fine.

To get the channel ID, simply turn on developer mode, then right-click on the channel you want to listen to. You should see a `Copy ID` menu button at the bottom of the context menu.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try this out and let you know if it works for me

Comment: Yes. I will. That's a very fair ask

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if you have permissions to add an actual bot to that server, or have a friend that can do this for you. Using your own account as a bot would be possible, but is against discord ToS and would get your account banned.